# How does AMQ's redeliver work? Does it hold a consumer completely during the redelivery process?

Tags: activemq-classic

Assuming that we only have one consumer and our redelivery policy will allow the message to be redelivered for a quite long time.

I've tried a scenario where I sent two messages(different type), one is designed to be redelivered and the other can be consumed normally.

It seems the normal message will be blocked if it is delivered later than the redelivered one.
It will not be consumed until the redelivered message has tried many times reaching the maximum redeliver times. That would lead to a situation where a easy-to-consumed message must wait a long time to be consumed..

I'm wondering how the AMQ redeliver work. When a message is redelivered in a consumer, the other message can be sent to this consumer until current message has been consumed or timeout(to DLQ).

Can someone help ? Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ActiveMQ's overriding concern when redelivering messages is to honour message ordering on a queue.

Given two messages A and B, which get sent to a queue with a defined redelivery policy as you describe: if a client fails processing A, that message will get placed back on the queue and no other messages will be consumed until A is consumed successfully.

Check out the [ActiveMQ Message Redelivery and DLQ Handling](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) section for further details.

---

Please remember to vote this response up if it answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I got that AMQ is will maintain the order on a queue. What I want is that the redeliver delay of A should not block the consume of message B even if message A is the first one on the to be consumed queue.. I do not want message A's delay to cause any other message delay either. Even if we define many consumers in client, somehow there is a chance that all the consumers consume same message type which is A(designed to be redelivered several times and according to redeliver policy that will take a quite long time, maybe 1h), that will cause our app lower efficiency. Thanks Jake.

Comment: Jakub is correct on this, however I want to add something. Your concern, Huawei, is valid, but you'll want to tune down your prefetch to avoid the situation you're describing. That way messages that might otherwise be blocked to one consumer, yet might be prefetched, can be dispatched to other consumers.

Answer (score 4):

For this case it is possible to set the ActiveConnectionFactory to onBlockingRedelivery.
Find details in de [ActiveMq Api documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html#setNonBlockingRedelivery%28boolean%29):